# I2C Slave on ATtiny841

Tags: avr, i2c, attiny, twi

I am using an ATtiny841 microcontroller as an I2C slave, but I have difficulty finding information on it. So for, all I have are application notes and reference code for TWI and USI module.

It seems like ATtiny841 has a unique TWI slave interface, which is slightly different. Although I could write out the code manually it would really help if there is a standard sample code that I can refer to.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does AVR311 not contain what you need?

Comment: AVR312: Using the USI module as a I2C slave http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc2560.pdf

Comment: @Ignacio: Yes, AVR311 is the one that I'm currently referring to. It is based on the more general TWI module found in ATmega controllers.

Comment: @vicatcu: I have used USI on other ATtiny controllers, but 841 does not have USI.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the TWI example code as-is, since TWI is I2C: [What is difference between I2C and TWI?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/50915/what-is-difference-between-i2c-and-twi)