# Writing I2C library - Philips trademarks

Tags: i2c

I guess is a very trivial answer for many but I am not sure in my case.
I am writing an open-source firmware, which might also get documented and commercial use is not excluded from who is using it.

This involves an I2C capability. Is there any issue in calling it I2C, or should I change the name? Like Arduino called it TwoWire, some IIC. Shall I invent a new name, or using a random name in the code and documentation? Are there some "free" namings for I2C?

If you want to downvote, please be constructive and/or address me to the right space.

Comment: no its fine, (IIC = I²C). TWI (two wire somthing) is name used before by Atmel (Atmega series) which i think is compatible with original Philips i2c bus protocol ..

Comment: See https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/50915/what-is-difference-between-i2c-and-twi

Comment: @PeterSmith I actually asked this after having read that question. I don't understand if that applies to the software using the hardware as well. From what I read, is not legal using the I2C naming on hardware without paying fees, but does this apply on firmware?
As far as I know, I am just using a lgal hardware, not making one by myself.

Comment: @thexeno - I am not certain but I believe it also applies to the actual protocol which is what you are controlling.

Answer (score 1):

IANAL but I've never heard of Philips (NXP or whoever) pursuing little guys over this. Somebody the size of Atmel, maybe, hence TWI.

Suggest you search for he I2C manual, UM10204.pdf (currently at https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/user-guide/UM10204.pdf ) Its "legal" section is only 1 page, not exactly threatening as these things go, mostly disclaiming liability, though it does claim one I2C-Bus trademark.

My reading would be :

1. somewhere prominent in the docs like "legal disclaimers" on page 1 (and especially in any licence agreement you have) include that trademark claim

> I 2 C-bus — logo is a trademark of NXP Semiconductors N.V.

2. and in the technical section. where you descrieb the I2C interface, refer and/or link to the User Guide, UM10204.pdf (link above) which is useful anyway

Then it is clear that you are making to claim to the IP, and actually steering other people towards NXP, and what corporation would sue you for free advertising?

Comment: "what corporation would sue you for free advertising?" Video game publishers would.

Comment: @DKNguyen Well there's always one. I remember a local builders merchant on the isle of Skye where I lived for a while, being sued by a fast food chain. Defence case rested on the owners having been Macdonalds for about 800 years.